# Angular: How to handle Observable in service with dynamic route?

Tags: angular

I have a MealsModule in my Angular app. Inside it I have SharedModule.

In the SharedModule, I have MealsService in the providers which uses FireBase as database. Here is my SharedModules:

```
import {ModuleWithProviders, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';


import {AngularFireDatabaseModule} from 'angularfire2/database';
import {MealsService} from './services/meals.service';
import {ListItemComponent} from './components/list-item/list-item.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ListItemComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule
  ],
  exports: [
    ListItemComponent
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [
        MealsService
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

This is my MealsService:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Store} from '../../../store';
import {AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';
import {AuthService} from '../../../auth/shared/services/auth.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {tap} from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface Meal {
  name: string;
  ingredients: string[];
  timestamp: number;
  $key: string;
  $exists: () => boolean;
}

@Injectable()
export class MealsService {

  meals$: Observable<Meal[]> = this.db.list(`meals/${this.uid}`)
    .pipe(
      tap(next => this.store.set('meals', next))
    );

  constructor(
    private store: Store,
    private db: AngularFireDatabase,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {
  }

  get uid() {
    return this.authService.user.uid;
  }

  addMeal(meal: Meal) {
    return this.db.list(`meals/${this.uid}`).push(meal);
  }

  removeMeal(key: string) {
    return this.db.list(`meals/${this.uid}`).remove(key);
  }
}
```

I have an issue with the meals$ Observable here. When I log out from my app, and log in with other user, the uid is not updated since observable is already registered and MealsService is never destroyed.

The current solution I have is to provide MailService directly in the component where I list the meals instead of SharedModule. This works since MealsService is destroyed with the component.

Is this the best approach or there is a better one?

Comment: you should reset service state after logout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that the `meal$` Observable is created only once, when the service is created.  Since the service is a Singleton, when provided in `root`, this value will never change and the dynamic url will be the initial value of `this.uid`.  When you provide this service in a `Component` a new service instance is created for each instance of the `Component` created and is destroy with each `Component` when destroyed.

To fix this, you need to reassign the Observable whenever authService updates the user.  This can be done providing an Observable in your AuthService and emitting a value whenever user is updated.  For example:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn:'root'
})
export AuthService {
    public user: User;
    public userUpdated = new Subject<User>();
    ...
    public login(user: User) {
        this.user = user;
        this.userUpdated.next(user);
    }
}

@Injectable({
    providedIn:'root'
})
export class MealsService {
    constructor(
      private store: Store,
      private db: AngularFireDatabase,
      private authService: AuthService
    ) {
        meals$ = this.authService.userChanged
           .pipe(
               mergeMap(user => this.db.list(`meals/${user.uid}`)
                  .pipe(
                      tap(next => this.store.set('meals', next))
                  )
               )
           );
    }

    get uid() {
      return this.authService.user.uid;
    }

    public meals$: Observable<Meal[]>;

    addMeal(meal: Meal) {
      return this.db.list(`meals/${this.uid}`).push(meal);
    }

    removeMeal(key: string) {
      return this.db.list(`meals/${this.uid}`).remove(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will do the same as my code. Observable will be created the first time the getMeals() is called and will never change.

Comment: In your example, the Observable is created when the Service is first created.

Comment: So? You just delayed the creation of Observable, but the problem stays the same.

Comment: My bad, I misread your question and missed the part where you had said that the Observable doesn't update when the AuthService's user changes.  I've updated my answer to solve that issue.

Comment: Great, I managed to get it working. I already have FireBase auth state observable in AuthService so I just subscribed to in in the MealsService constructor. Thanks!

Comment: That great!  I also realized that you can also use `mergeMap` on the authService Observable and just assign the result to meals$.  That way you don't have to assign it in the `Subscribe` method and manage that subscription.  I've updated my answer with that.